# IntelliJ - print out variables for debugging?

Tags: intellij-idea

New to intellij...how can I print out the contents of a variable in a window such as?

Some window with prompt?

> ? myStringVariable
>   "This is the contents here"

Comment: You are a bit unclear with your question. You mean you want to see value while debugging?
select that variable and press alt + F8

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is printing to the console enough?
Then: `System.out.println(myStringVariable)`

Other option for debugging is to (once in breakpoint) - right-click variable -> Evaluate expresion. Debugger will display the value of a variable (you can also get values for more complicated expressions).